# get end effector position in moveit in python

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am totally newbie to ROS and MoveIt,

I tried to use the one from the MoveIt tutorial, I used it to find Baxter Research Robot right hand position, but it doesn't work as intended.

any help is welcome,

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233935/get-end-effector-position-in-moveit-in-python/) by [andydar](https://answers.ros.org/users/26755/andydar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2016-05-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-05-09**:
If referring to any on-line tutorials or pages, please *always* include a link to those resources, as we cannot guess which one you are actually referring to, and it will make helping you much more difficult.

Also "it doesn't work" is *not* a good way to ask for help: what *did* happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See [Cartesian Paths](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/pr2_tutorials/planning/scripts/doc/move_group_python_interface_tutorial.html#cartesian-paths) section on the tutorial.

```
# You need to instantiate a Planning Group of your interest as `group`
waypoints.append(group.get_current_pose().pose)
```

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2016-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1